# How does expected minimum of a set of random variables decreases as the variance of the random variables increases?

Tags: random-variables, maxima-minima, variance, estimation

I was reading a paper on Addressing function approximation Error in Actor critic methods where they explain a benefit of their proposed method as follows:

[image]

I wish to build an intuition of this effect with either a proof or an example.
Thank you

Comment: Wow is hard to read and I believe needs more context (and some quotation marks and commas) to be more comprehensible, but anyway, I think only about your specific question: thinking in a random variable that takes only possible values with constant mean, that the expected minimum will be lower if the variance increases since is going to be on each "time-step" driving away from the mean, so if data is more spread with time, is natural to think than the minimum will be falling away, in this hypothetical example of positive RVs, running to be near and near to zero as time flies.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, think of two distributions (RVs) with the same mean.  If distribution 1 has a larger variance than distribution 2, the data will be more spread out.  Distribution 1 will likely have a smaller minimum and a larger maximum than distribution 2 because its values tend to be further from the mean.